# How to solve $r^3-6r^2+11r-6=0$

Tags: polynomials

> Solve $r^3-6r^2+11r-6=0$.

I know that the answer is $(r-1)(r-2)(r-3) = 0$, but how can I jump to this  step from $r^3-6r^2+11r-6=0$?

Comment: If $f(r)=r^3-6r^2+11r-6, f(1)=f(2)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Begin by noting that $1 - 6 + 11 - 6 = 0$, so that $1$ is a solution of the equation. Factor out a term of $(x - 1)$, and consider the remaining quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

$$r^3 - 6r^2 + 11r - 6 = 0\\
r^3 - 6(r^2 - 2r + 1) - r = 0\\
r(r^2 - 1) - 6(r^2 - 2r + 1) = 0\\
r(r - 1)(r + 1) - 6(r - 1)^2 = 0\\
(r - 1)(r(r + 1) - 6(r - 1)) = 0\\
(r - 1)(r^2 + r - 6r + 6) = 0\\
(r - 1)(r^2 - 5r + 6) = 0$$

By solving the quadratic equation $(r^2 - 5r + 6) = 0$, we get that $r_{1, 2} = (5 \pm 1) / 2$, so finally:
$$(r - 1)(r - 2)(r - 3) = 0$$